# Django queryset with isnull=True in get_object_or_404

Tags: python, django

I have 2 records in the posts table, one of the row in table has **rating as NULL** and the other has **rating as 2**, both have same user_id say 5

I implement this first

**views.py**

```
class Rating(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'base/rating.html'
    def get(self,request,slug,*args,**kwargs):
        user_id = request.user.id
        post = get_object_or_404(Post.objects.filter(user_id=user_id,rating__isnull=True))
        return render(request,self.template_name)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^post/addRating/(?P<slug>.+?)/$',views.Rating.as_view(),name="post_rating"),
```

> So the actual concept is not to render the view if rating column is
>   not null

So the first record with rating null should return 404 page but it is not and the second record display properly

Can any one help me to fix it?

Comment: If what you describe is correct, then neither of those would show the 404 page; one would get one post, the other the other. So probably your data isn't as you think, or `user_id` holds the wrong value.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich so lets ignore the second condition let focus on first, still both are getting displayed. user_id is also same

Comment: get_object_or_404 cannot possibly return both, it only returns one or raises 404. And you don't show us how you are displaying things.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich may be I am wrong I am trying to get correct things by placing what I am trying out. Can you correct it?

Comment: All I see is that line, which should get the post that has rating null. You should probably include the rest of your view, the urlpattern, the URLs you try and their results in the question.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich updated the question with my view and url

Comment: OK, so what's going wrong? The code you have should get a post (the one that has rating null), and then it ignores it and just renders a page. Isn't that what's happening?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the get_object_or_404. "Not render the view if rating column is not null" - OK, but you have two rows, so two rating columns, one of which is null and one of which is not null. What do you want to do?

Comment: So there are 2 records same user id, first record has rating null and second record has rating 2. Actually the second record's(Page) should render 404 because it is not null but it is not rendering 404 instead render the template

Comment: Ahh, your records have _different slugs_. And you mean to select the post with the slug from the url. You need to add slug=slug to the filter() as well.

Comment: The way the code is now, there is no "second record's page" -- there is only this page, it does the exact same thing regardless of which slug is passed as you never use that variable.

Comment: Please ignore the slug that is for entirely different purpose and do not relate with the current problem. To be more precise `rating__isnull=True` is not working

Comment: I am giving up, now you are saying there is even more to the story that is causing the problem but that you haven't included in your question. Enough wasting time.

Comment: I am not going to use the slug in this query that is for different purpose coming in the url. There is no relation between the slug and the post query which I have used

Comment: The thing remains -- it doesn't do different things depending on whether it's on "second record's Page" or whatever -- it looks at all the records with a given user_id, sees if one with rating__isnull exists, and if it doesn't then it raises 404. But one exists, so it renders the page.

Comment: Okay thanks I got it, I am wrong in somewhere else I will check. I believe your last comment helps me

Comment: @overflow if not object present get_object_or_404 will raise 404 page. But in you case user will be present means post will be present there. So that's why it's not raising any error.

Answer (score -1):

You need read more carefully the django doc, the above code is incorrect.
To use get_object_or_404, you have to write something like(from django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404))

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
def my_view(request):
    my_object = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=1)
```

For your propurse, you should write something like:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(user_id=user_id,rating__isnull=True)
post = posts and posts[0]
```

Comment: This is wrong, the doc you link to states that the first argument to get_object_or_404 can also be a _queryset_, which is what he does. And the other arguments may be empty, why not?